# how can I hide the src of a video html tag?

Tags: html, video, src, hidden-field

I want to have video stream without the user can view the src of the video in the html and js files with the inspect element option of the browsers.

I have reviewed some frameworks such as:

http://flowplayer.org/

http://www.jplayer.org/

But they show the src of the video.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to HTML5 video. What you're requesting is impossible.

Comment: If you don't want people to have your video, don't put it online.

Comment: Only way I can think of is to use a proxy.

Comment: If you're using Java you could use a servlet.

Comment: It's the internet. The source is always visible in any content you send over.

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine **streaming** options. Like **mms** stream & similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all, I used this option which permit give permission for download or not the video

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialStreamingFlowplayer.html

Answer (score -1):

if the src looks like src="*" check out 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/location-hide

If it looks different , ask him maybe he will add it